# ffmpeg Library not loaded

Tags: ffmpeg, gnutls

since updating ffmpeg, I get this error when using it:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gnutls/lib/libgnutls.30.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
Reason: Incompatible library version: ffmpeg requires version 59.0.0 or later, but libgnutls.30.dylib provides version 45.0.0
```

I've tried updating everything again and reinstalling but no luck

I'm using Mac OS 11.5.1

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using homebrew :

```
brew reinstall ffmpeg
```

Comment: Hi, author says that a reinstall doesn't solved the problem